# A file reader webservice

Tags: java, rest, apache-poi, mpxj

I want to create a restfull webservice that reads Excel,MPP files and gives me a list of beans for my application. Currently we are using jxl for excel reading and mpxj for mpp. Is there any  way i could generalize a  file reading service so that it could be reused .

Comment: Could you expand a little of what you mean by "generalize", perhaps makes some notes which describe in more detail what the service might do?

Comment: Agreed, you should be more specific. "that reads"... from where ? "generalize" what ? Just as a hint, at work we use a lot what we call "watch folders", i.e. Java apps that monitor a specific shared folder and do processing whenever a file is dropped (using JNotify). So you could implement such a watch folder and whenever a excel file is dropped, process it and send whatever information to your web service for instance.